# Html div won't expand when a table gets bigger

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my layout, i use javascript to get a xml-file and put it into a table. But the the table jumps out of the divs. I can't think of anything i'm doing wrong. Anyone see the problem?

http://andeers.com/testsite

Comment: We know what you *don't* want, but we need to know what behavior you expect in order to provide advice on achieving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably you have to clear the floats. add `overflow:hidden` for the `#content` selector in your css

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is nothing constraining the height of the div which you will need for the overflow to work. I suggest setting a height some height values in the css, either on the div containing the table or on a parent element.

Comment: Hm, it worked when i placed the overflow:hidden. No i can't see any bugs.